# Replaced special characters in file name. Now os.stat fails as they have double backslash

Tags: python

I did check around but don't have to-the-point solution for this.

I used below approach to replace special characters (brackets and space) with a leading backslash. When I print `f`, it shows correct output (filename has backslash), but when I use same `f` variable in `os.stat` command, I get an error that the filename does not exist. The file which is not found has double back slashes.

```
for ch in ['(',')',' ']:
        f = f.replace(ch,"\\"+ch)

print(f)
stat.S_IMODE(os.stat(f).st_mode)
```

---

Output (if `f` is "my file(1).txt"):

```
my\ file\(1\).txt
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my\\ file\\(1\\).txt'
```

Comment: have you tried `f = r"my file(1).txt"`. `r` considers everything as a `raw string`, there might not be a need to used the `for` loop

Comment: You would need to escape the round brackets and spaces when entering such a filename in the shell, but not in Python. There's nothing special about those characters in a Python string literal, and certainly nothing special once they're already in an `str` object. What is the actual filename returned by `os.listdir` when called on the directory containing the file? That's what should be passed to `os.stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try os.stat(f).st_mode without escaping the special characters in f?

This worked for me:

```
import os, re

f = "my file(1).txt"

print os.stat(f).st_mode
```

If you want to escape any special characters, you can just use

```
import re 
x = re.escape("my file(1).txt")
```

In the case of os.stat, it doesn't require escaping the special characters.